# Group $n$ numbers in $\mathbb{R}$ into $k$ clusters

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, discrete-mathematics, inequality, optimization

Let $x_1\leq x_2\leq...\leq x_n$ be a sequence of real numbers in $\mathbb{R}$. If we want to group the numbers into $k$ groups such that the sum of the within group squared error is minimized, it seems intuitive that the optimal clustering mechanism should be in the form:
$$\{x_1,...,x_{j_1}\}, \{x_{j_1+1},...,x_{j_2}\},...,\{x_{j_{k-1}+1},...,x_{n}\}$$
But how can we prove this mathematically with rigor? I've been thinking about this for a while but I believe it is not as easy as it seems to be.

By the sum of within group squared error, I mean, if $G_1,...,G_k$ is a partition of $\{1,...,n\}$, the sume of within group squared error is:
$$\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{i\in G_j}(x_i - \bar{x}_{G_j})^2$$
where $\bar{x}_{G_j}$ is the average of numbers in group $G_j$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Show that if a solution is not of this form, it can be improved.  That is, prove the contrapositive of "if optimal, then this form."

**Edit**: I agree that this approach is not so simple to flesh out.  [This link](http://wiki.objectvision.nl/index.php/Fisher%27s_Natural_Breaks_Classification) mentions that the following paper provides a proof:
[Fisher, W. D. (1958). On grouping for maximum homogeneity. Journal of the American Statistical Association, 53, 789-798](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2281952.pdf).  Indeed, the Appendix contains a proof that uses the same approach that I sketched: assume there is $x_r < x_s < x_t$ with $x_r$ and $x_t$ in one group and $x_s$ in a different group, and show that any such grouping can be strictly improved.

Comment: Thanks. But the difficulty is how to show the contrapositive?

Comment: Suppose you have a grouping that is not in specified form.  Then some group contains $x_i$ and $x_k$ and some other group contains $x_j$ and $x_\ell$ with $x_i \le x_j < x_k \le x_\ell$.  Do you see a simple way to improve the sum of squared errors?

Comment: There are much more possible scenarios. For example, $x_i<x_j<x_l<x_k$.

Comment: I recommend trying to first prove the case $k=2$ and all $x_i$ distinct.  The same idea of improving a solution that is not of the specified form works in the general case. Also, I shouldn't have used $k$ as a subscript when it is already the number of groups.  Suppose $x_r$ and $x_t$ are in one group and $x_s$ is in the other group, with $x_r < x_s < x_t$.  What happens if $x_s$ and $x_t$ switch groups?

Comment: I think the consequence of switching $x_s$ and $x_t$ is hard to tell, since it involves how other points are distributed. Is it?

Comment: I am sure we all understand you would like an exact answer and an ironclad proof. But you have not clearly stated your question (what do you mean by $j_1, j_2, ...?)$ and you have given us none of your thinking towards and answer or proof. So you should not expect complete answers. Maybe hints, strategies, clues, .... // Using $n$ 'clusters' of one observation each would leave you with MSE = 0.

Comment: Consider this example: suppose you have one group of ten $1$s and one $100$ and another group of one $12$ and one $14$; this has a much lower "sum of the within group mean squared error" than one group of ten $1$s and one $12$ and another group of one $14$ and one $100$ (sum of the within group mean squared error of $811$ compared to $1859$), so ordering the elements does not necessarily do better and you may need to do more to minimise the cost function

Comment: @BruceET Thanks for the comment. However, I believe that that the question is already pretty clear. It is evident that $j_1,j_2,...$ are increasing integers from the context. Also, your last '$n$ cluster' argument is definitely true but this is essentially for a particular choice of $k$, which is $k=n$.

Comment: @BruceET As for my thinking process, the most direct way, which is also my initial thought is just what you have suggested. However, this is so evident that I do not think it is worth pointing out. The difficult part is how to justify this 'switch and improve' statement. I believe this may even not be able to justified since there may be multiple optimal scenarios and the ordered grouping structure is just one of them.

Comment: @BruceET The link to the paper indeed solves my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an experiment. I start with 100 random observations
split into four groups.

```
x1 = runif(25,0,50);  x2 = runif(25,0,50)
x3 = runif(25,0,50);  x4 = runif(25,0,50)
x = c(x1, x2, x3, x4);  g=as.factor(rep(1:4,each=25))
```

Then the MSE(Within) = MSE(Resid) = 198.61.

```
anova(lm(x~g))

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: x
           Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
 g          3   316.7  105.57  0.5316 0.6617
 Residuals 96 19066.4  198.61
```

However, if I sort the 100 observations from smallest to largest,
the groups become more homogeneous, and MSE(Within) = 16.3, much
reduced.

```
y = sort(x)
anova(lm(y~g))

Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
g          3  17817  5939.0  364.07 < 2.2e-16 ***
Residuals 96   1566    16.3                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I'm not promising that this method gives you the *minimum possible*
MS(Resid). But this the first thing I thought of to *reduce* MS(Resid).

Notice that the total sum of squares is the same in both cases.
It will not change as you rearrange the same observations into
groups in different ways: 316.7 +  19066.4 = 19383.1 is the same
as 17817 + 1566 =  19383 (except for rounding error when the
values are rounded for display).

Also, notice that in both cases $\text{MS(Resid)}$ = $\text{SS(Resid)/DF(Resid)}$ = $\text{SS(Resid)}/96.$
So you can deal with $\text{SS(Resid)},$ if that is more
convenient.

Also notice that this is just a math problem without much to do
with statistical; practice. If you have four *normally* distributed groups,
combine them, sort them, and then split them into groups by
quartiles, you will no longer have normally distributed groups.
Here I used groups of 1000 observations each, in order to make
nicer histograms. Histograms for the normal groups are in the top
row and those for the sorted groups are in the bottom row.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the nice simulation. However, this is not quite what I'm asking. I'm mainly interested in the mathematical proof of the optimal grouping structure.

Answer (score 0):

I expect the average is tripping you up.  Here's an idea:

---

(1) Show that for any $a_1 \leq a_2 \leq \cdots \leq a_k$ (and $a_0 = -\infty, a_{k+1}=\infty$) that $$G_j = \left\{i : \frac{1}{2}(a_{j-1}+a_j) \leq x_i < \frac{1}{2}(a_j+a_{j+1})\right\}$$ minimizes
$$\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{i\in G_j}(x_i-a_j)^2$$
(note: at this step, we don't care if any of the $G_j$ are empty or not)

---

(2) Prove (or simply note, as it's a standard fact) that if $G_j$ is nonempty, then
$$\sum_{i\in G_j}(x_i-\bar{x}_{G_j})^2 \leq \sum_{i\in G_j}(x_i-a_j)^2$$

---

(3) If you care about making sure the sets in the partition are nonempty, suppose $G_j$ is empty and just take either the max element from $G_{j-1}$ or the minimum element from $G_{j+1}$ and put it in $G_j.$  As long as $k \leq n,$ this shifting around of elements can be done to make sure all sets are nonempty (and is easily seen to never increase the sum we're trying to minimize)

---

Now, just start with a partition $F_1, F_2, \ldots, F_k$ of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ which minimizes the sum.  Set $a_j = \bar{x}_{F_j}$ for $j=1,2,\ldots,k,$ reorder if necessary to make $a_1\leq a_2 \leq \cdots \leq a_k$ and apply all the above steps.